# logarithmic inequality.

Tags: calculus, inequality

> For each $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$, show that:
>   $$a^2 \log(a^2) + b^2 \log(b^2) - (a^2+b^2)\log(\frac{a^2+b^2}{2})\leq (a-b)^2$$

I've tried some things but nothing came out. I was thinking of using Taylor somehow but I can't see how to work it out.

Comment: Equivalently, if $f(x)=x\log(x)$, $\dfrac{f(x)+f(y)}{2}-f\left(\dfrac{x+y}{2}\right)\leq \dfrac{x+y}{2}-\sqrt{xy}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $b=xa$, where $x\geq1$.

Hence, we need to prove that $f(x)\geq0$, where
$$f(x)=(x-1)^2-2x^2\ln{x}+(x^2+1)\ln\frac{x^2+1}{2}.$$
But $$f'''(x)=\frac{4(x^2-1)}{x(x^2+1)^2}\geq0,$$ which gives
$$f''(x)=2-4\ln{x}+2\ln\frac{x^2+1}{2}-\frac{4}{x^2+1}\geq0,$$
which gives $$f'(x)=2\ln\frac{x^2+1}{2}+2x-4\ln{x}-2\geq0$$ and
$$f(x)\geq f(1)=0.$$
Done!

Comment: Do you mean $b=xa$ in the first line?

Comment: @Martin R I fixed my post. Thank you!